# Write single list to csv by column

Tags: python

The following code searches for words given in the list and when matched writes the line to a csv row by row.

I am trying to find a solution so that instead of writing by row only, the 1st item in the list is column1 and 2nd item to column2 and so on.

```
parm_list = ["electricalAntennaTilt ","iuantSectorId ", "eUtranCellFDDId "]
os.remove("Parm.csv")
#keyword = input("Enter keyword here: ")
with open('Parm.csv', 'w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["eNB", "Parameter", "Value"])

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    for i in parm_list:
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            with open(filename, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
                for line in file:
                    if re.search(i, line):
                        with open('Parm.csv', 'a', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
                            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                            writer.writerow([filename] + [line])


    else:
        continue
```

Current Output:

```
315655.txt electricalAntennaTilt                30

315655.txt iuantSectorId                        315655_1_4
```

Expected output:

```
315655.txt electricalAntennaTilt                30 iuantSectorId                        315655_1_4
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but change

```py
with open('Parm.csv', 'a', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
```

to

```py
with open('Parm.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
```

in the second loop.

Comment: Thanks arun chand, unfortunately that doesnt get me the output i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your txt files, so just a guess:

```
import csv
import os
import re

directory = "~/Desktop" # put here a path to your directory

parm_list = ["electricalAntennaTilt ","iuantSectorId ", "eUtranCellFDDId "]
os.remove("Parm.csv")
#keyword = input("Enter keyword here: ")
with open("Parm.csv", "w", newline="\n", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["eNB", "Parameter", "Value"])

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        row = [filename] # <--------- make a row for every file
        for i in parm_list:
            with open(filename, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
                for line in file:
                    if re.search(i, line):
                        row.append(line) # < ----- fill the row

         # write the row to the csv file
         with open("Parm.csv", "a", newline="\n", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you close the file every time? Beside of that, try iterating over parameters (`parm_list`) in an *inner* loop instead:

```py
parm_list = ["electricalAntennaTilt ","iuantSectorId ", "eUtranCellFDDId "]
os.remove("Parm.csv")
#keyword = input("Enter keyword here: ")
with open('Parm.csv', 'w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=["eNB"] + parm_list) 
    writer.writeheader()

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".txt"):
            with open(filename, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
                data = {'eNB': filename}
                for line in file:
                    if data.keys() > set(parm_list):
                        break
                    for pattern in parm_list:
                        if pattern not in data and re.search(pattern, line):
                            data[pattern] = line.strip()

                writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Thanks madbird. Your code works, except it results in the first instance of the word in the file only, instead of all of them.

Comment: It's not clear for me, how you are going to handle the situation when there's a number of keywords attributed to a metric 1, and none of them for metric2. So I'm not sure how can I help you with that.